# How to setup linting for a JavaScript project with d.ts files?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm updating an old project, and adding `.d.ts` files with it. However, when I run `npm run lint`, which is defined as `eslint src/**` in my `package.json`, the linter complains with

```
/path/to/project/src/index.d.ts
  2:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token type
```

I'm not using Typescript in my project, only in *that* file.

My current setup is quite simple, and I haven't modified much the default configuration

```
// package.json
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    ...
},
...

// .eslintrc
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": "2018"
    },

    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "import"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "import/extensions": [
            ".js"
        ]
    }
}
```

How would I resolve that error?

Comment: I would just exclude the .d.ts file from linting with `eslint src/**/*.js`. Is this what you want or are you asking for a setup to lint TypeScript files?

Comment: @GOTO0 excluding the `.d.ts` does the trick, and I'm not really interested to lint it. It would certainly be a bonus, but I only include that file out of courtosy. I'm not a fan of TypeScript, I try to avoid it in fact. It's only useful to me as a contextual help, and this is what it should've been from the start, as far as I'm concerned, not another layer on top of the language. This is what I hate about Microsoft, the embrace and expand mentality. /end of rant.

Comment: [Obligatory meme](https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/aN16DAb/aVle7NRr_700w_0.jpg) :D

Comment: @GOTO0 haha! :)

Comment: @YanickRochon, I'm having the same problem, but I want to lint the files :)
Any help there? I am using `@babel/eslint-parser`.

Comment: @ImperatorRomanorum, I am also creating type declaration files (d.ts files) for my JavaScript npm modules. Could you find a solution to lint d.ts files?